# jsp and .net data exchange

Tags: c#

please could someone give my more clarification of how I can Post from my jsp page data (username and password) to my c# controller (login.aspx.cs)?
Indeed I want to sent decrypted values (username and pasword) to c# controller for storing in Miscrosoft SQL database server.
Here is javascript function that i add to the head of my jsp page to post value. but how to retrieve those values from c#? many thank for help.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function do_submit() { 
     document.submit_form.method = "POST";
     document.submit_form.action = "http://localhost:49990/Login.aspx.cs";
     document.submit_form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain to me how this has anything to do with Java? Remember JavaScript ≠ Java

Comment: For the action you want the .aspx, not the .aspx.cs!

Answer (score 1):

Change your js submit action to:

```
document.submit_form.action = "http://localhost:49990/Login.aspx";
```

Then in your `Login.aspx.cs` code behind Load event do this to retrieve the posted values:

```
void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  var username = Request["username"];
  var password = Request["password"];
}
```

Assuming your form elements are named accordingly, no form html was posted so we have to assume.